# Externally specifying parameters for visuals in Azure Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have an application that is specific to a professional group who are not familiar with or trained in constructing visualisations — the Power BI UI is beyond their capability — the interface for my application is customised to lead the user through a series of steps that allow them to specify the question(s) they want answered from their data.

From their input I want to use a rules-based approach to specify the input that can be used by Power BI to generate a specific visualisation, including filters, etc and publish it as an interactive report for the user to interact with.

Has anyone worked out how (if?) the parameters for a visual can be fed to Azure PowerBI API to generate the visualisation and the report in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible to achieve all your requirements.

But the part about feeding parameters is possibly answered by my post on stackoverflow: [Passing parameters to Power BI filter programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571489/257470)