# How to Pass a URL Filter to a Power BI Publish to Web Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to pass a URL filter to a published report but am unable to get it to work.

The report:
https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOGExYjhhYmMtZmU0OS00ZGJjLWE3YmUtNTM5MjM1OWIzZTA5IiwidCI6IjUyM...

I've tried using the method here: [Passing parameters to Power BI filter programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555694/passing-parameters-to-power-bi-filter-programmatically) by adding &filter=Table1/ZipKey eq '00001' to the end of the URL but that doesn't work.

It works for this link:
https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/reports/8d3cbf1e-3d89-46d3-ac1a-b24d0784b125/ReportSection?filter=...

Any ideas?  Is this not possible?  If not, the end goal is to be able to embed this within another page, is there a different method I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you provided:
The report: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOGExYjhhYmMtZmU0OS00ZGJjLWE3YmUtNTM5MjM1OWIzZTA5IiwidCI6IjUyM [snip]

is a publish to web report. The query string filter option is not supported for publish to web reports.

If you want to do programmatically filter the report you should use one of our supported developer options:

A) https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-report-load-report-iframe/

B) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-iframe/

The second link you provided is a URL directly to the www.powerbi.com, where the URL filter syntax is also supported. Based on that option A may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, I've been trying to go sheen the embedded path.   I'll take a look at option 1.

Answer (score -3):

You wrote

`&filter`

.. but the syntax is :

`?filter`