# Microsoft Power Bi Publish to web embedded : update faster then in an hour

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

As I know Power BI caches the report definition and the results of the queries required to view the report.

It can take approximately one hour before changes are reflected in the version of the report viewed by your users.

Could this interval be decrease? Or could the caching be turned off?

Please help!

Comment: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-refresh-data/ ...Maybe you can set up a Live/DirectQuery

Comment: @Hackerman I use Hive as a Data Source. I'm not sure that it provides DirectQuery. At least I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Publish to web is designed for internet scale.  If you're looking to target internal users or as part of an application, you can use one of the authenticated embedding options -there's no cache there. Take a look at my answer here for a review of those options:
[How to Pass a URL Filter to a Power BI Publish to Web Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107694/how-to-pass-a-url-filter-to-a-power-bi-publish-to-web-report/38112651#38112651)

We are working on making the cache update time fast for report metadata. Essentially if you save the file in our service, the changes to the report definition will be updated immediately.

Any more details on your scenario would be helpful.

Comment: I have a simple web page with no server background. All I need is to show up-to-date power bi report on the page. Report is changing every minute.