# Passing parameters in powerBI report URL?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have to pass certain string in URL to set filter value in my PowerBI report.

I checked many articles and following caught my eye.

[Link to Stack-overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555694/passing-parameters-to-power-bi-filter-programmatically/38535546#38535546)

Here I see that he is passing postal code equal to one of the values in filter.

I want to do something similar except, i want to use contains instead of equal. 
I want filter to select all values where my provided string is present.

Ex: A project can have multiple tags, and I get them as 1 string in my data

1. Project1 : "#Tag A#Tag B#Tag C#"
2. Project2 : "#Tag A#Tag B#Tag D#"
3. Project3 : "#Tag B#Tag D#"

If i pass "Tag A" as part of my string then my report should show only data for Project1 and Project2 by default.

NOTE: I am new here, Please let me know if I should add/remove something from here. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power BI Embed URL-multiple filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943885/power-bi-embed-url-multiple-filters)