# Getting an error while trying to import data in Power BI using Spark in Azure HDInsight Connector

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI and Azure HDInsight. I am trying to import data in Power BI using the Spark connector, but I am getting the below error.

> We couldn't import data from Spark on Azure HDInsight.
>
> Make sure you are entering the information correctly.

The status code in the error message is 500.

Please provide any inputs.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Shreya Kaushik

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Status code 500 implies an error on your server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to Power BI filter programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555694/passing-parameters-to-power-bi-filter-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the Azure HDInsight cluster that we had created was of version 3.6 while the Power BI spark connector only supports version 3.5 currently.

Thanks all for your help!

Shreya Kaushik