# How to Embed a PowerBI Report having filters showing start and end date

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

How to embed Powerbi report that contains start and end date filter I have a embedded report but I have no clue how can I show some data between the Start and end date can somebody point me into the right direction for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Power BI to use a single slicer (filter) for two columns. Instead, you can use parameters.

Comment: This is not a case of slicer, Its the case of embeding the PowerBI report inside a web page and passing the start and end date filter inside the Javascript code so that report gets sorted out as per those filters!!

Can anything like this is possible.

Comment: Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555694/passing-parameters-to-power-bi-filter-programmatically. This might be helpful to you. @TheUser

Comment: I have seen this @Harshvardhan, but I have no clue how to use ODatafilter between the both the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working similar scenario this sample code could help for you. You can pass the filter value through js.

```
var Filter1 = {
  $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#advanced ",
  target: {
    table: "Transaction",
    column: "tx_date)"
  },
  logicalOperator: "AND",
  conditions: [
    {
      operator: "GreaterThan",
      value: "19-08-2016"
    },
    {
      operator: "LessThan",
      value: "19-08-2017"
    }
  ]
}

report.on('loaded', event => {
  report.getFilters()
    .then(filters => {
      filters.push(Filter1);
      return report.setFilters(filters);
    });
});
```

}